# I am new in backend developing and trying to create some api with Using nest and typeorm but cannot post in http://localhost:3000/users/

Tags: angular, rxjs, typeorm, nest

**Here I have created service for User create:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import { UserEntity } from '../models/user.entity';
    import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
    import { User } from '../models/user.interface';
    import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {
      constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private readonly userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
      ) {}
    
      create(user: User): Observable<User> {
        return from(this.userRepository.save(user));
      } //create user 
   
    }
```

**and here the post method for Create User which is getting 404-not-found-msg in postman when I want to check the API, can someone help me finding my mistake here, please**

```
import {
      Body,
      Controller,
      Delete,
      Get,
      Param,
      Post,
      Put,
    } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';
    import { User } from '../models/user.interface';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Controller('users')
    export class UserController {
      constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
    
      @Post() //this is the api I wanted to test in postman
      create(@Body() user: User): Observable<User> {
        return this.userService.create(user);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This error is showing: {"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot POST /users","error":"Not Found"}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am getting this error : {"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot POST /users","error":"Not Found"} although my create api is ok. (with nest)

Answer (score 0):

for post call you just need to change the route all the code is proper
Use below URL for POST method

> http://localhost:3000/users

Comment: I also checked with this url "http://localhost:3000/users" , but yet I am getting this: {"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot POST /users","error":"Not Found"}

Comment: did you add this user module in app.module ??

Comment: yes, and I have solved it, thanks.

Comment: what was the solution can you explain over here ??